# Removed public key while WCF Service is running

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have a setup with WCF Services and Certificates. I have removed public key from Service machine while WCF Service was running. But, still, the client is able to contact the service.

I am using Self signed certificates and Verisign SSL certificates.

Can anyone help about the facts behind this and why is it happening?

Comment: Most likely the certificates are read once, probably at startup and then cached. Restart IIS and re-test.

Comment: Did the certificate you deleted come from the current user of the local machine? Can you re-select it via the IIS website binding module? Maybe you deleted the wrong certificate. Also try to re-add a https binding, which may be caused by a local cache.